# Javascript - Problem with passing arguments to functions: passing them in diffrent order returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, arguments

I know it may be a silly question but I know how to pass information to functions like this:

```js
function test1(a, b) {
  alert("TEST1 a: " + a + " (should be: 2)")
  alert("TEST1 b: " + b + " (should be: 1)")
  }
test1(b = 2, a = 1)


// but if i switch the order when passing arguments
// like here:


function test2(a, b) {
  alert("TEST2 a: " + a + " (should be: 2)")
  alert("TEST2 b: " + b + " (should be: 1)")
  }
test2(a = 1, b = 2);
```

The problem is that if I switch "a" and "b" and pass the information in the diffrent order, my intended values will also change as shown above.

My function wont recognise the difference and will read "a" as 2 and "b" as 1. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Or is there a better method?
Or should I pass the information as an object? I'm not sure if passing "arguments" in an object is the right way to do it.

Comment: it's working fine, your comments in `test2` are wrong. what does not work? the arguments are ordered, not named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function and the order in which you should pass the arguments is fixed. You can pass an object instead, and use object destructuring to mimic the arguments.

```js
function test({ a, b }) {
  console.log("TEST a: " + a + " (should be: 1)")
  console.log("TEST b: " + b + " (should be: 2)")
}

test({ a: 1, b: 2 });
test({ b: 2, a: 1 });
```

If you care about the order in which the keys are passed:

```js
function test(arguments) {
  Object.keys(arguments).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`TEST ${key}: ${arguments[key]}`);
  })
}

test({ a: 1, b: 2 });
test({ b: 2, a: 1 });
```

Comment: Yes those 4 brackets and a few equality signs seems to fis the problem... The problem was that if i pass the information in a diffrent order that it would break my code. I took a challenge to build myself a small library that replaces the cursor with a page element like a <div> that can be styled and animated. and for it work it requires at least 3 arguments: offsetX, offsetY and the element that you want to replace a cursor with. offsetX and offsetY are the relative positions to the cursor. the element that replaces the cursor will have this offset to the actual cursor.

Answer (score 0):

**You changed order of parameters passed to function call not at the function definition.**

One way to achieve what you're trying to achieve is using `object` and `destructuring`.

```js
function test(input) {
  const {a , b} = input
  console.log("TEST1 a: " + a + " (should be: 2)")
  console.log("TEST1 b: " + b + " (should be: 1)")
  }
  
test({b : 2,a : 1})
test({a : 2,b : 1});
```

Comment: Yes and i want to know how to read the correct values even if their order is changed. + please read the title...

Comment: Well i tried it but i can't get it to work. Do you know any good related articles?

Comment: @Quiver what didn't worked ? look at above code. if still not found success let me know

Comment: My bad i messed up with one value... Anyway both methods now work fine for me. Yours and Callam's. But why using 'const' if the values from the object are already available as if they were variables?

Comment: @Quiver just for the sake of readability  it doesen't make any difference.